Is the power of Sanskrit described in the scriptures?
Krishna Dvaipayana Vyasa and other Rishis of Sanatana Dharma specifically chose Sanskrit for expressing the Vedas, Puranas and other ancient texts.
Sanskrit is known as a language which is well structured due to its rules which makes it ideal for poetic expression. Moreover, it is also called as Deva-Bhasha or the language of the gods.
Is there a mention about the language in the shastras (e.g. greatness of reciting Mantras in Sanskrit, association with Devi Sarasvati)?
